# "Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol." Trying to insert data via JDBC into Postgres from Google SQL

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, google-cloud-sql

Signed up for a Google Cloud SQL Account in order to store Adwords data via an adwords script into Postgres with JDBC.

I know that on SO there are two questions that asked basically what I'm asking:

- [Automate Google Spreadsheet data load from external database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901948/automate-google-spreadsheet-data-load-from-external-database)
- [Not able to connect Postgress database in Google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231886/not-able-to-connect-postgress-database-in-google-app-script)

But because of https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/faq (last question at the bottom) I'm asking this again since this might be related to the beta status of Postgres in Google Cloud SQL.

Getting the error message from title "Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol." which I identified via logger.log for the following line of code:

`Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);` with dbUrl being of the following string format:

jdbc:postgresql://myip/mydbname

Am I missing something or can someone confirm that this is not supported?

Comment: What's the *client*, where does that code you quoted run? Is it JavaScript run on a client app? (If so, how do you handle password security?). At a guess, whatever the client is doesn't understand the PostgreSQL JDBC protocol, and doesn't use native JDBC drivers like PgJDBC. Or you need to install PgJDBC.